# Minimise JavaFx window Using FXML

Tags: javafx, fxml

I am new to Javafx , i am working on javafx project . I want to minimise javafx window .
i use  primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED); . I also want to add clickevent to the imageview in fxml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work for you...

```
imgview.setOnMouseClicked(newEventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
    publicvoid handle(MouseEvent me){
        primaryStage.setIconified(true);
    }
});
```